# Js google api порядок вызова функций

Tags: javascript, функции, google-maps-api

Есть две функции: `initMap` и `geocodeAddressAndAddMarker`. При вызове `geocodeAddressAndAddMarker` из `initMap` читается адрес из инпута, и по сути должно дальше продолжаться выполнение функции ( заход в `geocoder.geocode` и т.д. ). Но выполнение как бы заканчивает на этом, возвращается к моменту вызова функции `geocodeAddressAndAddMarker`, выполняется дальше. Потом возвращается опять в `geocoder.geocode`, выполняется всё там и заканчивает.
Вопрос в следующем: в чем тут беда? это js так круто работает, или у меня руки "очень" ровные? И что делать, чтобы восстановить порядок вызова?

```
function initMap() {
    //массив с будущими маркерами
    var markers = [];

    /* тут была инициализация google карты */

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        geocodeAddressAndAddMarker(geocoder, map);
        //какие-то еще циклы, действия и т.д.
    });
}


function geocodeAddressAndAddMarker(geocoder, resultsMap) {

    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            console.log('мы внутри');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

собственно решение моей беды

```
function geocodeAddressAndAddMarker(geocoder, resultsMap, callback) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        console.log('мы внутри');
        //далее манипуляции с marker'ом
        callback(marker);
    }
}
```

Comment: В том что запрос к геокодеру асинхронный?

Comment: @u_mulder ок, но из функции геокодера мне бы желательно вытащить маркер и сохранить его у себя в массиве. но так это не работает. Есть какие - то варианты?

Comment: Значит надо передать в колбек геокодера ваш набор действий. В колбеке все и выполнится.

Comment: @u_mulder спасибо, понял в чем суть. Пошел курить callback'и

Comment: @u_mulder Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.